# Bus Question - the probability that the time till the next bus is larger than the time since the last bus.

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Question: The city bus arrives at a certain bus stop at the constant average rate of once per 30 minutes. Suppose that you arrive at the bus stop at a fixed time t. Find the probability that the time till the next bus is larger than the time since the last bus.

My thought: we can take advantage of $P(X>Y)=E(P(X>Y|Y))$ here.
Let S be the time of the last arrival, (if no arrival in [0,t] then define S=0.)
Here is what I got then:

$E(P(T>t−S|S))=P(T>t−S|S=0)P(S=0)+∫t0P(T>t−S|S=s)fS(s)ds$

Comment: What exactly does "the constant average rate of once per 30 minutes" mean? That the arrivals follow a Poisson process, or just a renewal process with a finite mean?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is symmetric in time. Since the probability that the two times are equal is $0$, the probability that a particular one of them is greater is $\frac12$ by symmetry.